# How to modify a getMessage for an exception?

Tags: java, exception

I need to change the return message of the method getMessage() ,
for instance, i have an ArithmeticException, and when I write:

```
try{c=a/0;}
catch(ArithmeticException excep){System.out.println( excep.getMessage() );}
```

and I execut this code I have: **/ by zero.**

So, I wanted to change this result by overwriting the getMesage method.
I have created a new class called **MyException** that **inherits** from **ArithmeticExceprtion** and I **override** the methode **getMessage**, and after that I have changed the type of the exception in my last code from **ArithmeticException** to my new name class **MyException**:

```
public class MyException extends ArithmeticException{
    @override
    public String getMessage(){
       retun "new code message";}
```

}
and I have changed the first code, I have wrotten:

```
try{c=a/0;}
catch(MyException excep){System.out.println( excep.getMessage() );}
```

and when I have executed this code, I had the same error's message as if I didn't catch the exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArithmeticException: / by zero
     at main.test.main(Test.java:33)
```

So, my question is: how can I change the message of the methode getMessage() ?

Answer (score 1):

You have extended the `ArithmeticException` with a new class called `MyException`. But the statement `c = a / 0;` still throws `ArithmeticException` but never `MyException` itself, so your `catch` clause is not reached.

Note that normally you shouldn't catch runtime (unchecked) exceptions like `ArithmeticException` since it denotes a programming error. Also note that for checked exceptions, the compiler shows an error telling you that the statement would never throw that kind of exception, but in this case, `MyException` is an unchecked exception so the compiler is fine with it.

In your particular scenario, you cannot change the message of the exception since it will always be an `ArithmeticException`. But you can always print whatever message you want in the `catch` clause. Or you can wrap the statement in a method and let that method throw the subclass exception:

```
public void foo() throws MyException {
   try {
        c = a / 0;
   } catch (ArithmeticException excep) {
        // handle excep
        throw new MyException();
   }
}
```

Comment: but we cannot add the block try/catch in the code of the function !?, we have to write it at the time when we call the function foo, isn't it @manouti ?